# HTML5 audio start playing delay

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, audio

My current implementation of MP3 audio playback works great, however in Chrome on an Android device there is a delay between the 'canplay' event being triggered (which starts a visual playback progress bar) and when the audio is actually heard through the device. This results in the visual progress bar being out of sync slightly.

Is there a more reliable way of detecting when audio playback commences than using 'canplay'?
My logic is as follows:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'something.mp3';
audio.play();
audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    // audio playback commences now.
    // start progress bar animation.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use timeupdate event to verify the currenttime of playback. Here is snippet from MDN documentation

`timeupdate` The time indicated by the element's currentTime attribute has changed.

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: The `playing` event is triggered before the actual playback through the device still. This can be a couple of seconds delay!

Comment: @user3554382 you may want to change the logic to use timeupdate event then. Use timeupdate for moving the progress bar?

Comment: Using `timeupdate` event and verifying `currentTime` is greater than 0 seems to be the most accurate way of detecting when the audio playback actually occurs. Thanks!

Comment: i am also using the timeupdate event in ionic but its lagging the audio any solution ?